# Footer bottom fixed

Tags: bootstrap

Как прикрепить футер к низу странницы, а не окна браузера, т.е. чтоб футер был всегда снизу... при помощи boostrap... помогите пожайлуста

Answer (score 1):

Документация Bootstrap **на русском языке** http://bootstrap-3.ru/bootstraptheme.php
Вот пример http://bootstrap-3.ru/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/